# TypeOrm, Postgres & NestJS: filter ManyToMany column

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using postgresSQL, Typeorm and NestJs in the development of a web application.
I have several entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(
    () => Property,
    { nullable: true, eager: true },
  )
  @JoinTable()
  properties: Property[];
}

@Entity()
export class Property {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    key: string;

    @Column()
    name: string
}
```

And i'm trying to get products by properties.
This gives in sql:

```
;with r as (
    SELECT
           bien.*,
           ARRAY['usage.toto'::varchar] = array_agg(p.key) as compare1
    from bien
    INNER JOIN bien_properties_property bpp on bien.id = bpp."bienId"
    INNER JOIN property p on p.id = bpp."propertyId"
    GROUP BY bien.id
)
select * from r
where compare1
```

Can someone help me ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

To access the `Product` table on the `Property` table you need to declare the bi-directional relation, as is said [here](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/bi-directional-relations). So, it will be:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(
    () => Property,
    property => property.products,
    { nullable: true, eager: true },
  )
  @JoinTable()
  properties: Property[];
}

@Entity()
export class Property {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    key: string;

    @Column()
    name: string

    @@ManyToMany(
      () => Product,
      product => product.properties,
    )
    products: Product[];
}
```

And now, to get the properties with their products, you will need to join, like this:

```
//...

const propertyRepository = connection.getRepository(Property);
const properties = await propertyRepository.find({ relations: ["products"] });

//...
```

Comment: It's not working, i've tried:      let queryBuilder = this.productRepository
            .createQueryBuilder("product")
            .leftJoin('product.properties', 'property')
            .where("('usage.stockage') IN properties")
            return queryBuilder.getManyAndCount(), and i got an error

Comment: I think your problem is on the `where`, what is `usage`? You have said that you want to "get products by properties." and in the code you show above you tried to get properties by products. I suggest you trying this:  `this.productRepository .createQueryBuilder("product") .leftJoinAndSelect('product.properties', 'property').getManyAndCount();` or try the code I've put on my response.

Comment: "usage.stockage" is one of my properties, i'm trying to get products with specific properties.
Something like products.findByProperties([''usage.stockage"]) will return all products with exact properties: ['usage.stockage'].
I'm not trying to return prodcut with properties field.
I don't know if i'm clear

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is clearer now. But `usage` is a column of `Property` table? Or `usage.stockage` is at name(or other) column on `Property` table? Following the second option will be: `this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder("product").leftJoin('product.properties', 'property').where("property.name = :propertyName", { propertyName: "usage.stockage"}).getManyAndCount();`.

Comment: usage.stockage is the value of column named 'key' of property table, that's correct. That's working for one, but i want to test with array, something like: this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder("product").leftJoin('product.properties', 'property').where("properties = :props", { props: ["usage.stockage", "usage.other"]}).getManyAndCount()

Comment: Sorry about the delay, with this information I think it will be:
`his.productRepository.createQueryBuilder("product").leftJoin('product.properties', 'property').where("property.key = :props", { props: "usage.stockage"}).orWhere("property.key = :props",  { props: "usage.other"}).getManyAndCount()`. I think it will work.